# How to align a div vertically on full unknown width?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I mean, if i have a div, with 200px of height and 200px of width, and i want to align it vertically (i can align it horizontaly with "margin: auto", but, is there a way to align it vertically without knowking the **height** of the screen?

Thanks and sory for my english, it's not my native language

edit: height of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/pLu69/)**</kbd>

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: but if the image is responsive, i'll have something like this:

`img{ width: 100%; max-width: 524px;}`

so when the screen width is smaller, that will not work anymore

Comment: @nick Yeah, in that case I recommend you jQuery ;)

Comment: do you know how to do it with jquery?

Comment: You could also use media queries to handle it differently once the window size gets below a certain threshold.

Comment: @nick I'm workin' on some fiddle for you at this moment.

Comment: @mdesdev thank you, waiting for it!

Comment: @nick I've updated the fiddle, check it out now, is that what you want?

Comment: seems it works fine on jssfiddle, gonna test it on my page and tell you! thanks anyway

Comment: @nick You're welcome and don't forget to include jQuery library.

Answer (score 3):

Centering things with table display is pretty handy... Take a look at this this:
http://jsfiddle.net/F9J4B/

Note that this is not "layouting with table"... It's just three divs that are using the table's display rules. No semantics rules are broken =)

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <p>Hello! I'm a DOM element. <br>I can be whatever size i want, and still still be in the center of things.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, 
html {
    height:100%
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;

}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Centering a box inside another box:

```
div{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

regardless of the size of the boxes.

The outer box may need `position: relative;` for the inner boxes' positioning to work.

Answer (score 1):

The Media Query handles the image when the screen gets too small.

```
.vertcenterdiv {
     position: absolute; 
     background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Square_200x200.svg'); 
     background-position: center center; 
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     background-size: 100% auto;  
     height: 200px; 
     width: 200px; 
     top: 50%; 
     left: 50%; 
     margin-top: -100px; 
     margin-left: -100px;
}
@media (max-width: 200px) {
     .vertcenterdiv {
          position: absolute; 
          height: 100%; 
          width: 100%; 
          top: 0; 
          left: 0; 
          margin-top: 0; 
          margin-left: 0;
     }
}
```